# Displaying non rectangular image with projector

Tags: projection, projector

I am trying to display a non rectangular image via a projector. Like this [image]

How does this work? Can a projector "display" a transparent background?

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with photography, so I'm voting to close this. However, you might have a photography-related goal, so feel free to [edit] to clarify. Regarding your question: transparant simply means the projector does not shine there, i.e. the projected imagepart is black. How black it actually looks depends on the ambient light and the reflectivity of the projector screen.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not clear how this relates to photography.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a pure black background. Then the background will project no light.

---

I must add several things.

1. The "blackness", or "non light" depends on the quality of the projector. Some cheap ones will still project a grayish background.
2. The image you are showing is not clear if is the case I am describing, because you probably have a lot of ambient light. The whiteboard does not know where the light is coming from.
3. Some projectors for photographic purposes use a cookie, this is a sheet of, let's say metal or cardboard with the shape you need. A quality projector needs a lens to focus a sharp silhouette of the shape. Then you will have a light silhouette and a completely black background. They are called **Gobos**. Google this: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=gobo+projector
4. You probably can use a gobo projector with photographic transparency. You can have a very dark black, especially if you use a film with a suffix or prefix "litho". This is a lithographic film with high contrast. Not for color images.

---

But at the end, the first sentence of my answer is the one you probably need.

Comment: Rafael, you are a god!